# How to edit youtube-dl command to include extra keyword in video filename

Tags: video, download, youtube, youtube-dl

How to edit this youtube-dl command such that the downloaded video filename becomes originaltitle_sitename.mp4

youtube-dl -o "/home/public_html/tmp/%(title)s%('sitename')%.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OezpYwuP2sY

Looking for your advice !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`extractor`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) field. The following command will produce `5 Crazy Inventions You Must have_youtube.mp4`:

`youtube-dl -o "%(title)s_%(extractor)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OezpYwuP2sY`

Comment: This is the answer that should be marked as correct.  The extractor is chosen by way of the URL's domain name.  It will work for all sites that an extractor exists, but will be left blanks for any site that uses the Default extractor attempt (does not have a pre-programmed handler).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to accomplish this from the command line itself but it is not possible as there are few options present for output format template (for the list of all possible output template visit [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md)). However this can be accomplished using Python scripting and code could look like:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

site_name="Site name you want to add"
url="URL of Video/Audio to be downloaded"
ydl_opts = {

            'outtmpl':"%(title)s"+site_name+".%(ext)s",
            'format': 'bestvideo',
            'noplaylist' : True
        }
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([url])
```